# How can I solve "bash: cd: /home/pi/AIY-projects-python: No such file or directory"?

Tags: python, api, voice, assistant

I am trying to setup google assistant sdk on my raspberry pi. I followed this [link](https://aiyprojects.withgoogle.com/voice)

But at the last item, when I entered the command `cd ~/AIY-projects-python` there is an error:

```
bash: cd: /home/pi/AIY-projects-python: No such file or directory
```

Comment: i don't know about it properly... can you please help me? my science fair is running.. but for this problem, i cannot show my project

Answer (score 0):

What does No such file or directory mean?

The error you got is an error you get when you are trying to edit or cd into a file or folder that doesn't exist.

---

If you have to create the folder, write `mkdir ~/AIY-projects-python`